# Does WebAPI fetch follow redirects?

Tags: javascript, http, web

Does [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) follow HTTP 30x redirects?

Comment: According to the [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-redirect-fetch), yes.

Comment: Depends on whether you configure it to do so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. [Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected).

> Checking to see if the response comes from a redirected request is as
>   simple as checking this flag on the Response object.

```
 if (response.redirected) {
   //...
 }
```

You can disable it:

```
fetch("awesome-picture.jpg", { redirect: "error" }).then(function(response) {
  //some stuff
}).then(function(imageBlob) {
  //some other stuff
});
```