# Does Javascript `fetch` follow redirects by default?

Tags: javascript, fetch

With regard to our modern set of browsers (circa November 2018) that support `fetch`...

If I `fetch` a URL like `https://example.com/` and receive a 301 or 302 response, does `fetch` automatically follow that redirect (by default), or something else?

Comment: Ah, I had searched but missed this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833868/does-webapi-fetch-follow-redirects Looks like "Yes, it does follow" by default, according to MDN citation there. For some reason that question was downvoted... yet here we are, people of the internet, asking a question... ‍♂️

Comment: Dang, look at that---learn something new every day. Thanks for sharing!