# How does Javascipt handle url redirect response from the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, url-rewriting

URL redirect:

1. Enter url in browser
2. Browser sends request to web server
3. Web server responds back to the browser with the new url
4. Browser sends a new request to the new url
5. Webserver directs the request to handler and sends back response to the browser

URL rewrite:

1. Enter url in browser
2. Browser sends request to web server
3. Web server re-writes the url and passes it to the handler and sends back response to the browser

The browser is designed to handle both of the above.

However, when I make a url request via javascript (or jquery) located on the html page, then how does the api call handle redirect response from the server?

Comment: "_The browser is designed to handle both of the above._" - No, the browser has no knowledge whatsoever on whether URL's are rewritten on the server side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does WebAPI fetch follow redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833868/does-webapi-fetch-follow-redirects)

Comment: @Ivar - by handle I meant the fact that both work fine with browser.

Comment: Rewrites work fine, but the browser is most definitely not _designed_ to handle it. It has no notion of it at all. But that being said, requests in JavaScript automatically follow 3xx redirects, unless you specifically disable it (in case of the `fetch` API).